# D3 Javascript HREF Link Concaternate

Tags: javascript

I am trying to show a link, that concaternates with the d.id on my screen.

Background: I have different items that I can call via the following schema:

```
https://1234.abc.com/#/id
```

I tried the following to get the id of a node:

```
info += '<div class=f><a href="https://1234.abc.com/#/"' + n.id + '>Go to </a> </div>';
```

But what I receive in the console is like

```
<a href="https://1234.abc.com/#/" 68="">Go to</a>
```

So i need to get the "68" in my example into my URL.

Would be great if someone could help me.

Comment: `<a href="https://1234.abc.com/#/"' + n.id + '>` should be `<a href="https://1234.abc.com/#/"' + n.id + '">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tiny bug. Try using:

```
info += '<div class=f><a href="https://1234.abc.com/#/' + n.id + '">Go to </a> </div>';
```

It's just the closing quotes that are misplaced.